# Search a string with multiple occurences in a text file using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am having a text file whose contents are as follows:

```
 The breakdown of MMS submissions by interface is... 
|    MM1 to MM1: 522245 messages (10.0% of submissions)
|    MM1 to MM3: 99360 messages (1.9% of submissions)
|    MM1 to MM4: 2393327 messages (46.0% of submissions)
|    MM3 to MM1: 14948 messages (0.3% of submissions)
|    MM4 to MM1: 2171419 messages (41.7% of submissions)
 ------------------
| The breakdown of MMS retrievals by interface is... 
|    MM1 to MM1: 2488980 messages (93.3% of retrievals)
|    MM3 to MM1: 11453 messages (0.4% of retrievals)
|    MM4 to MM1: 166323 messages (6.2% of retrievals)
```

I want to fetch values `522245`, `99360`, `2393327`, `14948`, `2171419`, `2488980`, `11453` and `166323` and populate in another sheet.
Please provide your inputs to do the same as I am unaware of search functions that can work on text file as in this case.

Comment: no i want to fetch those values too .I just gave sample value.Please let me know how I can do it

Comment: Easily done with regex.

Comment: @JLILI Aman can you give an example?

Comment: I am confused how to search second instance of value corresponding to MM1 to MM1 as InStr returns the location of first intance of MM1 to MM1

Answer (score 2):

Here's a concrete solution to your question:

```
Sub GetNumbers()
'1. grab text from txt file using VBA stream reader
Dim txtpath As String: txtpath = "d:\t.txt"
Open txtpath For Input As #1
'2. read stream into a string type
Dim str As String
Do Until EOF(1)
Line Input #1, txtLine
str = str & txtLine
Loop
Close #1
Dim regex As Object
'3. regex
Set regex = CreateObject("Vbscript.regexp")
 With regex
.IgnoreCase = True
.MultiLine = True
.Pattern = "\s(\d+)\s"
.Global = True
End With
'4. paste values in the active sheet
Dim i As Integer:  i = 1
If regex.test(str) Then
For Each Match In regex.Execute(str)
ActiveSheet.Range("A" & i) = Replace(Match," ","")
i = 1 + i
Next
End If
End Sub
```

result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If your data is in ColumnA with each cell starting "MM", then please try in B2 and copied down to suit:

```
=MID(A2,FIND(": ",A2)+2,FIND(" ",MID(A2,FIND(": ",A2)+2,10))-1)
```

For VBA turn on Macro Recorder first and import text to Excel if necessary. Select ColumnB, Copy, Paste Special, Values and copy results to desired sheet.

Comment: Can you please provide the code to import a text file into an excel.Currently I am browsing the text file and directly working on it .Is there a way to import the contents of the file in an excel

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution:

```
Sub ReadFromTextFile()
    Dim strFile As String: strFile = "C:\Users\Desktop\Tests\ReadFromText\ReadFile.txt"
    Dim strLine As String
    Dim strExtract As String
    Dim nLastRow As Long
    Dim nFnd As Long
    Dim nFndSpace As Long

    nLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    Close #1
    Open strFile For Input As #1

    Do Until EOF(1)
        Line Input #1, strLine
        If InStr(1, strLine, ":") > 0 Then
            nFnd = (InStr(1, strLine, ":")) + 2
            nFndSpace = InStr(nFnd, strLine, " ") - nFnd
            Cells(nLastRow, 1).Value = Mid(strLine, nFnd, nFndSpace)
            nLastRow = nLastRow + 1
        End If
    Loop


End Sub
```